# How do I set up Android ADB?

Tags: software-installation, adb

My computer is a Sys76 Lemur running Maverick, and my phone is a Nexus S running stock Gingerbread. I want to set up to use ADB (android debug bridge). I installed the Android SDK per instructions on the SDK website, but ADB doesn't work. Can someone help me with directions that are specific to Ubuntu?

Comment: As of October 2017, all other answers are outdated. You can download [ADB and fastboot directly from developer.android.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34702/how-do-i-set-up-android-adb/964987#964987).

Comment: are the packages available through a repo now?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/213874/how-to-configure-adb-access-for-android-devices

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Install adb & fastboot via PPA

You can install from the WebUpd8 PPA which support both 32-bit and 64-bit. Granted you can install directly from google. But I prefer to use PPAs to keep everything up to date.
*Works for Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04.*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Source: [Install ADB And Fastboot Android Tools In Ubuntu Via PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/install-adb-and-fastboot-android-tools.html)

## Install Android SDK via PPA

If you want to install the SDK which will allow you to update everything you can install via the upubuntu ppa.

So first thing is to add the ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/sdk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-sdk
```

Only issue at this point is that android-sdk needs to be run as root. Well the link in the menu didn't do much. So I updated the link in the menu, you can also run:

```
gksu android-sdk
```

From there you will need to install "Android SDK Platform-Tools" I also recommend updating "Android SDK Tools". You can deselect anything else you don't need.

**Now you will need to set your environmental variables.**
First you will need to make everything executable.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /root/android-sdk-linux
```

Now to add the variables.

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add these lines *(at the top)*

```
#AndroidDev PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:/root/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/root/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

Source: [Install Android SDK Manager (Revision 20) From PPA On Ubuntu 12.04/Linux Mint 13](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/07/install-android-sdk-manager-revision-20.html) 

Source: [AndroidSDK - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK)

Comment: It's not needed to compile `adb`, so installing with the android-sdk it's not from source. Furthermore he tags the question with 10.10, so this answer doesn't work. Great is, that this solution provides a 64 bit version.

Comment: Yeah my bad. Didn't notice that is was for 10.10. But hopefully it will help others. As for the source I meant "source" as google.

Comment: Yes, if anyone wants to install it, but in this case the question was how to set up after install.

Comment: none of this worked for me on 16.04. gksu did nothing other than ask for a password

Comment: `nilarimogard/webupd8` don't contain android-tools-* and `upubuntu-com/sdk` is outdated

Answer (score 22):

## Ubuntu 14.04+

Since Trusty the `android-tools-adb` and `android-tools-fastboot` packages in the Universe repository provide, respectively, `adb` and `fastboot`.

To install them:

- Enable the Universe repository: `sudo add-apt-repository universe`
- Update the APT cache: `sudo apt-get update`

To install `adb`:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

To install `fastboot`:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-fastboot
```

Comment: What's the difference between the [android-tools-adb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/devel/android-tools-adb) package and the [adb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/devel/adb) package? Both claim to provide the Android Debug Bridge.

Comment: @DanDascalescu `apt show android-tools-adb` says is a transitional package. AFAIK adb should be used.

Comment: these are now available in the general repo's?

Answer (score 7):

## 2017-Oct update

You don't need to install any package on Ubuntu 16 to get ADB working. No setup is necessary.

Simply download the official [SDK Platform-Tools for Linux](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html) from Google and extract `adb` and `fastboot` from the zip file.

Comment: can these now just be installed directly with apt and the standard repo's?

Answer (score 3):

I'm only guessing but perhaps you need to make sure Ubuntu is looking in the right place. As it says on the website, make sure you have added the directory that adb is located to your $PATH by adding `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools` & `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools` to your **.bashrc** and running `source .bashrc`

Comment: It works :o) with one small correction, export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/

Answer (score 1):

@mywebslave answered it perfectly, I just want to add one more thing to that. If you're running a 64 bit machine and doing an offline install, you may have to install the 32 bit compatibility libraries as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250173/3835769).

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

**Update:** The above command works only if you're running 13.04 and below. For newer versions `ia32-libs` has been replaced by other packages. See [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools).

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pre-requisite: [Install the Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556884/how-to-install-android-sdk-on-ubuntu)**

On Linux systems you will find `adb` and `fastboot` under `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools` directory. Just add this as `bin` and you're good to go e.g.

```
sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb
```

Comment: What creates `~/Android/Sdk`? That directory doesn't exist on my Ubuntu Linux system.

Comment: This is a bad solution, because after adb is updated in `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb` the versions of adb will not match anymore and you will not be able to run adb. It is better to make a symbolic link in `/usr/bin/adb` instead

Comment: This is actually a perfect solution if you already have android SDK installed