# How to configure ADB access for Android devices?

Tags: sudo, android, root, environment-variables, adb

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and I have installed Android SDK, set it's path in my user `.bashrc` and it works.

The problem is that my phone requires adb to be ran by root for permissions, but running adb with sudo I get the following error:

sudo: adb: command not found

I tried to simply use `sudo -E adb start-server`, but it doesn't work. Tried to add the export path line to `/root/.bashrc` and (after realizing it didn't help) to `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

I remember I could set it on my Arch Linux, but I guess my problem now is connected to Ubuntu root account not behaving like I expect it.

---

What I don't understand is the following:

These don't work:

```
martin@alyx:~$ sudo adb devices
sudo: adb: command not found
```

This does (typing the full path):

```
martin@alyx:~$ sudo /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
CM7-Blade   device
```

This doesn't work (using -E with sudo):

```
martin@alyx:~$ sudo -E adb devices
sudo: adb: command not found
```

This works (as root):

```
martin@alyx:~$ sudo su
root@alyx:/home/martin# adb devices
List of devices attached 
CM7-Blade   device
```

I'm totally confused now and I'd appreciate some clarifying on how to set a path for sudo or how else I could solve my problem.

(And please, don't say adb shouldn't be ran as root.)

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
By requiring root permissions I mean that I need them because otherwise I get:

```
$ adb devices 
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

which doesn't occur as superuser. Sorry if it was misunderstanding.

Comment: I've noticed with both Windows and Ubuntu that Android devices often do not appear if you have them plugged into a USB 3 port, plugging them into a non-USB3 port alleviates the issue.

Comment: from the docs: https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#configuring-usb-access

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Please read the following first: [How do I set up Android ADB?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34702/40581)

---

## Configuring USB access

First, you don't need root permissions to run ADB if you have set the permissions accordingly. The AOSP site provides examples for [Configuring USB Access](https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing#configuring-usb-access) for Pixel/Nexus devices. You can use the following scheme for non-Nexus devices:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="xxxx", ATTR{idProduct}=="xxxx", MODE="0600", OWNER="<username>"
```

Vendor and product ID can be obtained by using `lsusb` and searching for your device. (Note: The device actually is a Galaxy Nexus.)

```
$ lsusb | grep -i samsung
Bus 002 Device 103: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II]
```

So my `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` udev rule looks like this:

```
# adb protocol on maguro/toro (Galaxy Nexus)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0600", OWNER="username"
```

You may want to repeat this for the other phone states like fastboot if needed. To let the changes take effect either reload udev (`sudo udevadm control --reload`) or reboot (recommended).

## Making programs available

Instead of [modifying the path variable](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/40581) I would suggest adding a symbolic link to the executable either in `~/bin/` (user only) or in `/usr/local/bin/` (system wide).

```
mkdir ~/bin/
ln -s /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb ~/bin/
```

Comment: I tried adding the udev rules for my phone, but it didn't help so I thought maybe I wasn't clear about my problem. Please, if you have the time, see the end of my question.

Comment: Have you added the correct IDs? http://www.modaco.com/topic/329317-guide-ubuntu-and-the-blade/ Have rebooted your machine afterwards? `adb devices` works for me without root privileges.

Comment: Yay, it works! I added the udev rules to /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android-rules and apparently it was a mistake. After using /lib/udev/rules.d/11-android.rules, everything was fine! I don't need root persmissions! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Had the same ????????????    no permissions situation and your answer solved it, thanks.

Comment: for some reason it did not work here, I had to start adb server with sudo; any idea where could I look to see why it did not work?

Comment: `sudo` or no `sudo` this solution is not functional on Ubuntu 14.04. The list of devices is always empty.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Comment: I haven't needed ANY of this in the past year+ of using Ubuntu 16. This answer might be outdated. `adb` just worked on Samsung S7, Nexus 5X, Pixel and Pixel 2.

Comment: @DanDascalescu It's supposed to work out of the box, only when it doesn't one is looking for answers and the advice about the udev rule is still correct if it doestn't exists for a specific device as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 28):

I bumped into the same issue with a tablet from China (some weird manufacturer).

In addition to `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file, I needed to change `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` as well.

Run below on terminal;

```
sudo gedit ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

and your `adb_usb.ini` file should look like:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
# ie 0x2207
0x<!!!Your Vendor ID here!!!>
```

Disconnected and reconnected device and also needed to run below commands on terminal;

```
adb kill-server
```

and afterwards

```
adb start-server
```

And the device was detected.

Comment: I tried with your tip too but nothing changed, any idea where I could look to see why it did not work here?

Comment: Nice one. That worked for me. Along with that, [I had to update my adb](http://askubuntu.com/q/630259/151667).

Comment: This solution does not work on Ubuntu 14.04. The list of devices still comes out empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Uygar, finally I've found the solution that works for me.

Comment: That's what I was missing. In fact, the `0x2207` in your example is the same vendor ID that my device uses.

Answer (score 2):

In my case instead of MTP mode some Smartphones needed just to be set in PTP mode unlike most devices who required MTP mode to be detected by my Android Studio (v1.5.1).

So be sure to first try both MTP and PTP modes before without need spending time to the more complex ADP Configuration of Unix and maybe harming them.

In newer devices you can choose it directly at Dev options, while in older it is in the USB Connected Options on the Status Bar.

Yet also for me the newest Sony Xperia Devices from Z5 and above, will not work no matter the USB mode. Maybe my Android Studio is old or I need to dig also with the Unix ADP Configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. **Set android vars**

   Initially go to your home and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> it will show you hidden files now look for `.bashrc` file, open it with any text editor then place 
   the lines below at the end of file:

   ```
   export ANDROID_HOME=/myPathSdk/android-sdk-linux
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
   ```
2. **Reboot**
3. **Using device to debug**

   Listen for connection:

   ```
   adb -a
   ```

   Connect your Android device and authorise it:

   ```
   cordova run android --device
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Configuring USB Access**

The recommended approach is to create a file at `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`.

Please type in Terminal:

```
wget -S -O - http://source.android.com/source/51-android.txt | sed "s/<username>/$USER/" | sudo tee >/dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules; sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Those new rules take effect the next time a device is plugged in. It might therefore be necessary to unplug the device and plug it back into the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer helped me to get things done, I still was confused about:

```
martin@alyx:~$ sudo adb devices
sudo: adb: command not found
```

and especially

```
martin@alyx:~$ sudo -E adb devices
sudo: adb: command not found
```

since according to `sudo --help`:

```
-E, --preserve-env          preserve user environment when running command
```

It turns out, that on many linux distributions (that includes Debian and Ubuntu) `secure_path` and `env_reset` options are turned on by default, which reset your `PATH` variable and set it to `secure_path`. You can change it in the `/etc/sudoers` file using visudo.

Alternatively you can run:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH adb devices
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this seems voodoo but buy a **new high quality USB data cable**. Many cables are only designed for charging. I'm around with this issue for ages following all the suggestions and so on, with constant lost connection, and a good high quality USB data cable made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I personally faced the problem where my device with a USB C port was showing up in lsusb but not in adb devices.

I tried all solutions given like adb kill-server, configuring `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file, `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` file, setting the adb rules https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules and restarting but nothing helped.

What finally worked was connecting the device to a USB2.0 port. I had a new desktop so most of the ports were USB3.0.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command: `sudo tools/android update sdk --no-ui`

**SDK README:**

> Welcome to the Android SDK!
>   The Android SDK archive initially contains only the basic SDK tools. It does
>   not contain an Android platform or any third-party libraries. In fact, it
>   doesn't even have all the tools you need to develop an application.
>   In order to start developing applications, you must install the Platform-tools
>   and at least one version of the Android platform, using the SDK Manager.
>   Platform-tools contains build tools that are periodically updated to support new
>   features in the Android platform (which is why they are separate from basic
>   SDK tools), including adb, dexdump, and others.
>   To install Platform-tools, Android platforms and other add-ons, you must
>   have an Internet connection, so if you plan to use the SDK while
>   offline, please make sure to download the necessary components while online.
>   To start the SDK Manager, please execute the program "android".
>   From the command-line you can also directly trigger an update by
>   executing: `tools/android update sdk --no-ui`

Comment: I'm not sure that this addresses the original question...