# ADB cannot see my tablet (Pipo S1)

Tags: android, root, tablet, udev

I am unable to access my tablet (Pipo S1) through adb - after running `adb devices`, there are no devices visible. USB debugging is enabled, and I have tried 2 different USB ports and cables.

I was able to find the vendor ID through `lsusb`, which is `2207`. I added this ID to `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules`, `51-android.rules` and `99-android.rules`, after reading different conflicting information online. The exact line I added was:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="2207", MODE="0666", GROUP="adbusers"
```

Even after multiple server restarts, unplugging and re-plugging the device, I am still unable to see it. Any ideas? My end goal is to root this tablet without resorting to windows based apps.

Comment: Hidden in a comment to the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/213874/how-to-configure-adb-access-for-android-devices is the hint to put the .rules file to `/lib/udev/rules.d` rather than to `/etc`. Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Still no devices found after moving the files and restarting adb.

Comment: Sorry to hear, but it looked like worth a try. Here same issue btw.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the "**adbusers**" group exists in you system. If not, try to change it to "**plugdev**" in rules files, and add yourself to "**plugdev**" group.

In my case, i've just to install **android-tools-adb, android-tools-fastboot, android-rules** via apt, and edit files: **/lib/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules**, **/lib/udev/rules.d/51-android-rules.rules** for replacing "**adbusers**" with "**plugdev**". So now my tablet's rule looks like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however instead of using Ubuntu, I managed rooting my tablet through a Windows VM.