# I can't connect to my Firefox OS device

Tags: mozilla, adb

I've bought a [Firefox OS mobile](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/os/devices/#spice_fireonemifx2) lately and I thought of flashing it with a new version of Gaia. According to MDN, I gotta set up ADB in my computer. I've done all that. But, over the last few hours, I'm having a major trouble connecting my device to my computer. In order to `make-reset` Gaia, I need to have connected to my device.

I ran `lsusb`, and I've found this as my device

> `Bus 002 Device 043: ID 1782:5d24 Spreadtrum Communications Inc.`

So, I updated my `50-android.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d` with the following information:

> `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1782", ATTR{idProduct}=="5d24", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev", OWNER="wafflespeanut"`

<sup>I also tried the methods suggested by [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/341696/151667) answer & [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/461736/151667) answer, which didn't make a difference :/</sup>

Every time I made a reasonable change, I rebooted my system. For other minor changes, I just pull the cable, logout/login and try connecting it again.

But, despite of whatever I do, whenever I run `adb devices` (along with `udev restart`, `kill-server`, `start-server`), I get nothing other than this default string.

> `List of devices attached`

... which doesn't encourage.

So, is there anything I might've overlooked, or any ways at all to connect my mobile? Can you please help me out?

Comment: In my android-rules I only had to specify subsystem, the idvendor attr, mode, and group to get my tablet to connect to adb. Maybe try removing the other entries? Just a guess though.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Yeah, that's what I did at first. I added the other entries only when I found that the conventional ones had failed to work.

Comment: What version of adb are you running?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: `apt` says that I'm running the latest version (4.2.2, I guess).

Comment: Try typing `adb version` in a terminal.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Oops, it says 1.0.31. I first ran `apt-cache policy android-tools-adb` which said 4.2.2 (which must've been the entire package)

Comment: I had to go install 1.0.32 for some reason.  I don't know if that is worth the trouble for you though.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: It now shows some device! Wait, I'll check it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: It worked! My device is now shown in `adb`. I dunno how it did, but thanks to you. You can write that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try installing version 1.0.32? I may have had to do that to get it to work.  But it's been quite a while.

Comment: It somehow worked (I never imagined a [simple version change](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/97327/25084) would make a difference). It now shows a device. Thanks :)