# adb not detecting my device even if USB debugging is enabled and phone is rooted

Tags: phone, adb

I have A Gionee M2 device which is rooted and Usb debugging enabled.I have installed adb and fast boot on Ubuntu 13.04 and downloaded the "dualboot.sh" file from: http://humpolec.ubuntu.com/latest/dualboot.sh
I have also created 51 android rules file and added my device ID but its not detecting my device though its listed under "lsusb"

- This Is My Device listed:

  [image: This Is My Device listed]
  [image]
  [image]
- The cable is not charge-only:

  [image: The cable is not Chargeonly...]
- I added my device id to the 51 Android.rules file

  [image: I added my device id to the 51 Android.rules file]

Comment: What is the output of `adb version`?

Comment: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31

Comment: Have you added 0x"idVendor value" to your ~/.android/adb_usb.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the only problem, but you will most likely need to update to version 1.0.32 to succeed.  See this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630259/i-cant-connect-to-my-firefox-os-device).