# "adb devices" command won't detect my 4.4 Android phone

Tags: 14.04, drivers, android, adb

I've been having a issue trying to get the `adb devices` command to pick up my [LG TRANSPYRE™ (VS810PP)](http://www.lg.com/us/cell-phones/lg-VS810PP-transpyre) phone.  Keep in mind the command does in fact work.  So it's not an issue with adb, more with the drivers.

After taking a look from [this post](http://esausilva.com/2010/05/13/setting-up-adbusb-drivers-for-android-devices-in-linux-ubuntu/) I found online, I did the steps properly (three times, just to be sure).

So I basically did this:

1. Created a file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules`.
2. Wrote `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"` to the file.
3. Assigned proper permissions via `sudo chmod a+rx /etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules`
4. Rebooted my computer.
5. Restarted udev.

And the results:

```
$ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

(But nothing came after that)

But I didn't give up just yet.  I read from [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461729/ubuntu-is-not-detecting-my-android-device) here on Ask Ubuntu, I tried again.

Again, the process:

1. Created a file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`
2. Wrote `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTR{idProduct}=="1004", MODE="0666"` to the file
3. Gave proper permissions `sudo chmod a+rx /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`
4. Rebooted the 'pooter.
5. Restarted udev.

The output is the same as above, still not fixed...

I've very new to android, but my best guess is that I'm using some sort of out-dated method, because those posts are at either 2 or more years old.  So there is probably a new method now.

**Edit:**

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 1004:628a LG Electronics, Inc. 
...

$ dmesg | grep "LG"
[   69.824457] usb 5-1.4: Manufacturer: LG Electronics Inc.
[   73.155776] usb 5-1.4: Product: LGE Android Phone
[   73.155783] usb 5-1.4: Manufacturer: LG Electronics Inc.
[   74.232275] scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            LGE      Android Platform 0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   78.191262] usb 5-1.4: Product: LGE Android Phone
[   78.191268] usb 5-1.4: Manufacturer: LG Electronics Inc.

$ echo "0x1004" > ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

Comment: Do you have USB debugging enabled on your phone?

Comment: @the_Seppi Yes.

Comment: Mint isn't supported here. This is on topic on [unix.se]

Comment: Are any devices detected by the kernel when plugging the phone? Check the output of `dmesg`. Please note that Mint is off-topic here. You may want to ask on http://unix.stackexchange.com or rephrase your question so it fits for Ubuntu (but please check first whether this appears in an official Ubuntu system, an Ubuntu live system on USB should fit that.)

Comment: @the_Seppi, when doing `lsusb`, I get `Bus 005 Device 005: ID 1004:628a LG Electronics, Inc.` as one of the entries.

Comment: Please use the [edit] function to add information to your question. What about `dmesg`?

Comment: When doing `dmesg`, there is too much output for me to be able to identify anything (it output's so much in fact, it gets truncated by cutting off at the top.)

Comment: I tried greping the output.  See the edit to the post.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Set mode from [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) to [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol). I had the same problem.

MTP means *Media Transfer Protocol*. PTP means *Picture Transfer Protocol*, which means that the phone appears to the computer as a digital camera.

To set the mode: *Settings* > *Developer Options* > scroll down to Select *USB Configuration*, tap this and select PTP or just click at notification in status bar and select PTP.

Comment: Perhaps this is a problem in themselves LG phones

Comment: Thanks! I've been struggling for quite some time until I found this answer

Comment: additionally do this :          Go to Settings -> About phone -> Tap on "Build number" seven times. Voila !!!  this enables Developer mode ...         You will see new option called 'Developer Options' in the setting.
        From there I also had to enable USB debugging. Developer Options > USB Debugging ...  adb kill-server  ...  
adb start-server

Comment: What does this mean "set mode from MTP to PTP"?

Comment: I had to allow adb and USB debugging explicitly on CM13. See comment from Scott Stensland how to enable

Comment: Selecting PTP did not change anything for me. Still no devices detected. Same for selecting Charge only, MIDI, Audio and all the other modes.

Answer (score 34):

This happens to me sometimes with certain devices. Here's what I find works:

1. **Find the Vendor ID**: You can do this by typing `lsusb`. My output is something like this:

   ```
   Bus 002 Device 097: ID abc1:1234 Fictional Company, Ltd.
   ```

   In this case, `abc1` is the Vendor ID.
2. **Create an `adb_usb.ini` file**: Run the following

   ```
   echo "0x<your device's Vendor ID>" > ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
   ```
3. **Restart `adb`**

   ```
   adb kill-server
   adb start-server
   ```

Since doing that, my devices have all shown up in `adb devices`.

Comment: It didn't appear to work.  Check the edit on the main post I did.

Comment: That's too bad :( I have no other ideas at this point, the adb_usb.ini file works for me

Comment: I'm glad you got this answer in there before the off-topic police arrived. Solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I had issue, that occasionally Ubuntu wouldn't find my connected Android device. Now it found it after adb restart.

Comment: Great answer, allowed my adb to see my OnePlus 2

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Added the device following the normal instructions, but it wasn't enough, it wouldn't show. This made it work. Thanks a lot dude.

Comment: Had this issue with a no-name tablet, neither the authorize computer dialog wouldn't appear. Your answer fixed it. Thanks!