# ADB / Android Studio not recognizing my physical device?

Tags: android-studio, adb

In Android Studio, the list of devices and emulators doesn't list my physical device when I plug it in (Google Pixel 2). I've tried adding the device ID found w/ `lsusb` to the `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` as described in the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632651/adb-devices-command-wont-detect-my-4-4-android-phone), but to no avail :(

My only hint at what's going on is when I plugged the phone in for the first time, *no dialog appeared* asking if I trusted my computer. I recall this happened on my desktop computer where it works fine.

Any ideas greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit:**

My pixel is running Android version 10, and when plugged in it's in 'File transfer/Android auto' mode. However I have tried switching it to PTP without any luck. Running `adb devices` returns an empty list of connected devices, USB debugging through `chrome://inspect` doesn't list my phone either, killing and restarting the adb server doesn't seem to change any of this.

Comment: Check whether USB debugging is switched on or not. Also, check, in which mode is your phone in. When connecting your phone, keep the mode to **Charge device**. By the way, what is the android version of your phone?

Comment: More detail is required as you have mentioned a post where things are discussed in quit detail. But you have not mentioned/ shared if you have tried anything and the result output which include USB Debugging, adb devices, PTP, adb kill-server etc.

Comment: @Ajay I've updated my original post with more details, thanks!

Comment: Ah, it turns out my developer options got reset on my phone and the developer menu wasn't showing up. Had to install a 3rd party app as a shortcut to developer options and re-enable usb debugging. All is well now. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: Well LOL good to you.