# Android Studio - No USB devices detected

Tags: usb, android

I am running Android Studio on Ubuntu. I connected my LG phone with USB into my laptop, but when I run Android Studio it says `no USB devices or running emulators detected`

I even followed all the steps at this link: [Ubuntu is not detecting my android device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461729/ubuntu-is-not-detecting-my-android-device)

But that didn't help. Anyone know why? Is it because my LG phone is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the developer mode on the phone?

If not go to the settings on the phone and touch, I am not sure what line to touch but I think the line that shows the build number.
Touch that line 10 times. If it worked, the android shows you a message like "You are developer now."

There is a new line at the bottom of the settings in the phone. Like "developer options". Touch that. Now enable the usb debug option.

When you do that, your phone should be available in android studio.