# Is there an emulator or wine type environment that would allow use of android apps on linux?

Tags: android, emulation

Basically, I have a kindle fire that uses a form of the android OS and was wondering if there was a way I could run similar apps on my Ubuntu system. Specifically I'd like the news reader program "Pulse". 
Anybody know if such an emulator or workaround exists?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/1732/44179

Comment: Does [Bluestacks](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbluestacks.com%2F&ei=fkDuUMfnPKqP2gWtu4GgBw&usg=AFQjCNEUwBhsISBYDsenjhMifbGO9qCluA&sig2=hpB7eWDqO4nIPk5IAk3rvQ&bvm=bv.1357316858,bs.1,d.b2I) run on Wine?.

Comment: This was not a duplicate, but that post did kinda answer my question. Like literally, all I want to do is run one or two apps that my kindle has. So an emulator or native or whatever. I'll take it. But if I run it through an emulator will this inhibit my ability to sync between my laptop and my kindle? I.E. if I read a story on the laptop.. will it sync online so my kindle will show it as being read the next time i open the app?

Answer (score 4):

There is [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) which you can run inside [virtualbox](http://virtualbox.com) or vmware and then install the virtual device (virtual phone or virtual tablet) inside genymotion....and then emulate your  apps

Comment: Genymotion works like a charm. But only x86 (not ARM).

Answer (score 2):

At this time no, you can use the ADT emulator. Also there are VM x86 images you can use. However that is not what you are looking for.

In theory though because things are written in java and run off the dalvik jvm . It is quite possible someone can port dalvik to GNU like system with a X11 back end. This is all theory though, but I'm surprised someone has not done it yet.