# Is there an android emulator for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, android, emulation

Preferably one that works properly,like blue stacks on windows..

Thanks

Comment: see my accepted answer here => http://askubuntu.com/questions/773604/is-there-a-wine-equivalent-for-android-apps/773616#773616

Answer (score 5):

[Genymotion](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-android-emulator-ubuntu-linux/) (source of this answer; website also has some images on how this looks) is a complete set of tools that provides a virtual environment for Android. It can be very useful for developers, testers, salesman or even gamers. Genymotion is free for personal use. For full features, you need to buy a license.

Features:

```
OpenGL acceleration to achieve the best 3D performance
Enable full screen option and improve your experience
Be precise in your UI development with the “pixel perfect” functionality
Start multiple virtual device at the same time
Override virtual device identifiers
Directly command virtual devices sensors with Genymotion Shell
Fully compatible with ADB. You can control your virtual device from the host
Manage sensors: Battery level / status, GPS, Rotation, Camera
```

Since 2.1:

```
supports copy/paste from the host to the virtual device, 
  or from the virtual device to the host using Android builtin copy/paste feature.
Android 4.4 support
```

---

You need virtualbox, have to [register](https://cloud.genymotion.com/) (it is free) and download the installer to your downloads directory and then ...

```
cd ~/Downloads/
chmod +x genymotion-2.1.0_x64.bin
./genymotion-2.1.0_x64.bin
```

If you install it in Downloads you start it with:

```
/home/handbook/Downloads/genymotion/genymotion
```

It is free for personal usage and to me seems to be the better one amongst all the emulators.

Comment: Hi Rinzwind, it's me again ;) . I tried running genymotion on ubuntu 14.04 but I get got this error 

vihaan@Trojan:~/Downloads/softwareDownloads/genymotion/genymotion$ ./genymotion
./genymotion: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

any ideas ?

Comment: You need to install the dependencies that app needs. Look for libgstapp in your apt repo using `apt-cache search libgstapp`

Comment: Not working in Ubuntu 14.
"failed to create drawable"

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384645/2920227