# Android games on ubuntu

Tags: games, microsoft

I just started using Ubuntu recently. Is there a way to run Microsoft games in Ubuntu. I referred to the solutions in Ubuntu forums but couldn't find an easy working solution. Now, I have to switch between Ubuntu and Windows every time I want to play a game.

Note: I am looking for March of empires running on Windows. Not an Android game emulator!

Comment: Are there some specific games you are looking for?

Comment: Android? Microsoft? Do you mean Microsoft's Android games?

Comment: Yes, march of the empires

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I run Android apps on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1732/can-i-run-android-apps-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @muru March of empires is a Microsoft game which you can run on Windows. It has Android version too which is slow!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to run such games on Ubuntu. One way should be to use emulators like steam https://store.steampowered.com/app/702320/March_of_Empires/

Still, since you are looking for an easy solution, the best will be to run Windows from Ubuntu. Follow these steps: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18768/run-windows-in-ubuntu-with-vmware-player/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking specifically to run Android apps on Ubuntu, you can try [Anbox](https://anbox.io/). Bear in mind that it is still in alpha stage, though.